# Script5 access denied in IE9 in same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, multi-upload

I'm developing a site in django, which uses a jquery multi file upload plugin.

When i register to my site, a confirmation email is sent to my gmail account, i click the activation link and my website is opened in a new tab. I login, then I try to upload a file and it fails in IE9... F12 says "Script5 access denied"

However, if I type the link in the URL address bar instead of clicking the link in my email it works perfectly. It allows my to upload anything I want.

Im testing in a development server, and the host name is `http://192.168.0.1:8085`

My problem is that when i access my site via the email link, it just doesn't work... i checked the headers and the only thing that changes is that when i open the page from my email link, there is one extra header, `HTTP_REFERER = http://192.168.0.1:8085:/activate/16834e18a471d4f654aa763b2b22f203/` but besides this, i cant find anything else that could be causing the problem... and i cant understand why  when i type the url it works correctly.

The jquery multiupload plugin im using is: 
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

My script is:
http://pastebin.com/2JE8Qrnm

And this is the HTML:
http://pastebin.com/fyP0Z4sB

Comment: This error seems to only be reproduced with gmail...  

I found an easy way for everyone to reproduce it:  

1. In your gmail account, click on "Compose"  
2. In the body of the email add http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ as a link.  
3. Send it to your own inbox  
4. Now go to your inbox and open the email.  
5. Click on the file upload link, this one should open in a new tab  
6. Press F12 so the debug tool of IE opens up  
7. Now select some files, and click the upload button  
8. Check the concole in the IE debugging tool, it should say "Script5: access denied"

Comment: Error seems to be right at https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js#L122   line 122

just after the submit, it just says access denied...

Comment: I am having a similar problem - did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

hm... what jumps into my mind first:

try to add:

```
response['p3p'] = 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'
```

and/or:

```
response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

to your response.